# Should id field be optional or not?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

For example, I have entity `Person` which can be obtained from DB, or inserted into DB.

```
class Person {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

`id` field is autogenerated column in DB, so in situation when model is obtained from DB it will be always filled.

But when creating model, we are to set `name` and `age` fields.

So, in case, when we getting model from DB - `id` field is not optional and is always set. In case when we creating new model to insert into DB `id` field should be unset, and therefore in model definition should be optional.

Are there any best practices or common approaches to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an interface and add one more layer of abstraction such as:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Entity {
  id: string;
}

interface Input {}

class PersonEntity implements Person, Entity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class PersonInput implements Person, Input {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

However, I would probably just sanitize, validate, and insert the values directly into DB without turning them into a class instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
According to your solution, won't it be an overhead creating multiple classes/interfaces for every model?

Comment: @carcade In terms of computational cost, in most cases it's negligible. Besides, the typescript interfaces are only for static type checking when transpiling typescript to javascript.

Comment: I suppose you could use abstract class to make it DRY if the redundancy of the code is your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```js
interface PersonInput {
    name: string;
    age: number
}

interface PersonOutput extends PersonInput {
    id: string
}

class PersonInput implements PersonInput {
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) { }
}

const personInput = new PersonInput('John', 42)
```

AFAIK, you are not allowed to create `PersonOutput` object with `id` - you can only obtain it from your DB. Hence I think that your `PersonInput` class should expect only two properties `name` and `age`. Since, `PersonOutput` is a subtype of `PersonInput`, you should have some base interface, like `interface PersonInput`.

Interface `PersonOutput` should extends `PersonInput`. That's all.

Comment: I think you should google domain driven design and type driven design